# Desplazar elemento dentro del padre, queda por dentro

Tags: html, css3

Estoy diseñando un menú con html y ccs, el cual mostrará los submenús con hover. Estoy teniendo problemas para que el menú de tercer nivel no se esconda dentro del segundo:

[image: nav-third-level]

En el enlace de jsfiddle se encuentra el código.
https://jsfiddle.net/shinseiki86/k6btsevm/

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el segundo nivel estás haciendo uso de overflow-x y overflow-y para conseguir las barras de scroll.
Si comentas esas líneas y asignas el atributo overflow:visible verás como el tercer nivel ya no se ve limitado por la caja del segundo nivel.

Así a bote pronto no se me ocurre una solución que permita mantener esa estructura de HTML, las scrollbars y el tercer menú sobresaliendo.